# how to mock the constructor an static public class to throw exception

Tags: java, mockito

I am learning mockito and power mockito so forgive me if this question is dumb.

I am trying to mock the following line to throw some exception:

```
new ResultJSONWrapper.Success(null).toJSON();
```

I think I need to some how mock the constructor of success class to throw JSONException but couldn't find any solid solution to it.
Can some one please give me some hints?

```
public abstract class ResultJSONWrapper {
    private String json;
    public String toJSON() {
        return json;
    }

    static public class Success extends ResultJSONWrapper {
        public Success(Object result) throws JSONException {
            JSONWriter writer = new JSONStringer();
            writer.object();
            writer.key("status");
            writer.value(HTTP_OK);
            writer.key("data");
            writer.value(result);
            writer.endObject();
            super.json = writer.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You try mocking the JSONStringer constructor to throw the exception on whenNew using powermock(ito)?

Answer (score 0):

Mockito does not allow you to mock constructors and the Power Mockito is the last thing you should use.

Since the `ResultJSONWrapper` is an `abstract` class you can just create your `TestResultJSONWrapper` implementation that will throw `JSONException` during creation and will be past to the part of the code you are testing

```
public class TestSuccessMock extends ResultJSONWrapper {
    public TestSuccessMock (Object result) throws JSONException {
        throw new JSONException();
    }
}
```

So basically my advise here is to just not use Mockito for this purpose

Comment: tnx for your response - but the Success in your example is a method whereas in my situation it is a public static class which is already implemented

Comment: Mispelling - I meant it is constructor, edited already. Yeah what I mean is to not provide to the tested code the `Success` instance but the `TestSuccessMock` one - if the `Success` instance creation is somewhere hardcoded in you code it obiously means that anyway you are not able to mock this

Comment: I see- tnx for the update - would u provide some example on how to use this ? Am I mocking TestSuccessMock ?

Comment: `TestSuccessMock` is already a mock - as I said, I suggest not to use Mockito in this place at all. I don't know how your code look like - but if it's someting like `new YourTestedClass(new ResultJSONWrapper.Success(new Object())` it would be then `new YourTestedClass(new TestSuccessMock(new Object())`